# Having an Issue with K-Means Clustering in Python

Tags: python, k-means

I have some code that was originally for creating a cluster scatter point with 2 columns of data.  I have a dataset with 5 columns that I wish process.  So I have amended the code to allow this, but I'm getting an error and have no idea how to proceed.

The dataset has a header row with Time, PM2.5 µg/m³, PM10 µg/m³, O3 ppb, TEMP °C, and Relative Humidity % (I don't have a high enough reputation to post a screenshot).

So the columns that I am clustering are B through F (Not so interested in time at the moment)

And here's the python code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300,  relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='k-Means Clustering')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(200, 25, window=label1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Type Number of Clusters:')
label2.config(font=('helvetica', 8))
canvas1.create_window(200, 120, window=label2)

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

def getExcel ():
    
    global df
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    read_file = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)
    df = DataFrame(read_file,columns=['PM2.5 µg/m³', 'PM10 µg/m³', 'O3 ppb', 'TEMP °C', 'Relative Humidity %'])  
    
browseButtonExcel = tk.Button(text=" Import Excel File ", command=getExcel, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 70, window=browseButtonExcel)

def getKMeans ():
    global df
    global numberOfClusters
    numberOfClusters = int(entry1.get())
    
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=numberOfClusters).fit(df)
    centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    
    label3 = tk.Label(root, text= centroids)
    canvas1.create_window(200, 250, window=label3)
    
    figure1 = plt.Figure(figsize=(8,8), dpi=100)
    ax1 = figure1.add_subplot(111)
    ax1.scatter(df['PM2.5 µg/m³'], df['PM10 µg/m³'], ['O3 ppb'], df['TEMP °C'], df['Relative Humidity %'], c= kmeans.labels_.astype(float), s=50, alpha=0.5)
    ax1.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], c='red', s=50)
    scatter1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1, root) 
    scatter1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH)
    
processButton = tk.Button(text=' Process k-Means ', command=getKMeans, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 170, window=processButton)

root.mainloop()
```

I am able to import the file, and choose the number of clusters.  And, if I choose only 2 columns, I get a lovely scatterplot.  However, if I try to increase the inputs to 5 rows, I get the following error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\steev\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-85-26ae8f7b854f>", line 48, in getKMeans
    ax1.scatter(df['PM2.5 µg/m³'], df['PM10 µg/m³'], ['O3 ppb'], df['TEMP °C'], df['Relative Humidity %'], c= kmeans.labels_.astype(float), s=50, alpha=0.5)
  File "C:\Users\steev\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1589, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
TypeError: scatter() got multiple values for argument 'c'
```

Also, is there a way that I can export the results to a file as well as getting the scatter plot?

Comment: First of all, it is not about Kmeans it is about plotting (using matplotlib). In this line you are giving more values into `scatter` function. You should only give 2 different values. instead of this `ax1.scatter(df['PM2.5 µg/m³'], df['PM10 µg/m³'], ['O3 ppb'], df['TEMP °C'], df['Relative Humidity %'], c= kmeans.labels_.astype(float), s=50, alpha=0.5)` try this `ax1.scatter(df['PM2.5 µg/m³'], df['PM10 µg/m³'], c= kmeans.labels_.astype(float), s=50, alpha=0.5)`

Comment: Hi....  I have been able to do that, and it works.  What I am trying to do is a scatter with more than 2 values.  Is this not possible?

Comment: It is doable like this `ax.scatter(df['PM2.5 µg/m³'], IndexMaybe, color="b");
ax.scatter(df['PM10 µg/m³'], IndexMaybe, color="r")` I wrote as IndexMaybe I am not sure what kind of plot you what exactly

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what I'm doing.  At the moment, I'm just trying to see patterns.  I've got a bunch of sheets with pollution data and I'm trying to see if there's patterns with temperature and humidity and the levels of pollutants.  It's for a Uni project where I want to see if lockdown had an effect on pollutants on a particular street, and then comparing that to a drop in asthma cases.